# problem running a setInterval () inside a while in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to run a setInterva () but when trying to do it within a while cycle the setInterval() never runs. I'm a beginner in javascript so I don't know what the reason is.

The code I try to execute is the following:

```
var i = 0;

while(i < 5){

    var c = 0;

    var t = setInterval(function(){
      c++;
      if(c==5){
        clearInterval(t);   
      }
     },2000);

    i++;
}
```

What is the method to create a time.sleep() within a while cycle in javascript?

Comment: Code makes no sense. You are looping to create 5 different intervals, which are loops themselves. Once the first one gets to 5 the rest will clear as well. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You're starting 5 interval timers, but you're overwriting `t` each time. So when you do `clearInterval(t)` it only clears the last one. They're also all incrementing the same variable `c`.

Comment: You should either be using `setTimeout` to create one timer each iteration, or use `setInterval` once and have it clear itself when the counter reaches 5.

Comment: Why do you think `setInterval()` never runs? The function doesn't do anything visible.

Comment: Hello friends, I explain, I come from the python language and in that language there is the function time.sleep () that is used to sleep a while loop for a certain time. I only try to do the equivalent of that in javascript and setInterval () is the closest thing I found in javascript. How can I make a cycle wait 5 seconds in javascript

Comment: The interval will run in that code however it will only run once since all variables are overwritten and the first 4 have no chance of finishing. You also cannot tell if the last interval runs or not because there is no logs to console or anything confirming it, the fact that a runtime error doesnt occur is your best evidence. For what you have said in your last comment, to make a cycle every 5 seconds in Javascript, you just need one setInterval call, e.g. `setInterval(function() { console.log("test");
}, 5 * 1000);` (Units are in milliseconds)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, `setInterval()` does not pause code execution. Instead everything else runs as normal, but after the set amount of time it runs the function. Also, you want to use `setTimeout` because it only runs once. It looks like you just want to increment `c` by one every five seconds. Do so like this:

```js
let i = 0;
let c = 0;

while (i < 5) {
    setTimeout(() => c += 1, 5000/*number of milliseconds you want to wait*/ * (i + 1))
}
```

so, `i` will increment after 5000 milliseconds, 10000 milliseconds, 15000, etc.

Just so you know: `() => i+= 1` is the same as

```js
function() {
    i += 1
}
```

With some refactoring, and using `for` loops, your code becomes:

```js
let c = 0
for(let k = 0; k < 5; k += 1) setTimeout(() => c += 1, 5000 * (k + 1))
```